# HttpRuntime.Cache not suitable for web farms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, memcached

I've heard that `HttpRuntime.Cache` is not suitable for use with web farms. Why is that? What are some good example workarounds to this problem? I have heard about [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) and similar offerings but I cannot find any good recent sample showing basic usage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One problem with HttpRuntime.Cache in a server farm is that much of the data in the cache will be duplicated across servers.

For example, lets say you have an e-commerce site and you store the product catalog in the cache (since it rarely changes) and that takes 20M of memory.  If you have 5 web servers, each of them will have their own copy of the product catalog in their cache, using a total of 100M of memory (20M * 5 servers).  Using a shared cache like memcached eliminates that waste by storing only one copy of the cached items instead of 5 copies (one for each server).

Another problem is cache synchronization. Again, let's say you cache your product catalog for 1 hour after retrieving it from the database.  Each server could have a copy of the catalog in its cache that expires at different times.  When the cache expires on one server, it could get updated data that the other servers don't have yet.

This could result in a strange user experience where they might see 50 products in a category, then refresh the page, are sent to a different server, and see 51, refresh again and see 50 again, etc.  With a shared cache, you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: I agree. How would I go about implementing shared cache?

Comment: @tamasInagy - That's beyond what I could answer here.  Doing a google search for "memcached for .net" seems to yield some good articles though.

Comment: Consider AppFabric. I'm currently on that :)

Answer (score 2):

The [HttpRuntime.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx) object is an instance of [System.Web.Caching.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx).

According to the MSDN docs for the Cache object:

> One instance of this class is created per application domain, and it
>   remains valid as long as the application domain remains active.

On a webfarm, you have multiple machines handling the load of the site, so sometimes your request might go to machine A, and sometimes it might go to machine B, etc. If you stick something in the Cache on machine A, and then your next request goes to machine B, you will not be able to get it out of the Cache. This is like the limitation you have for InProc for [Session management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586). To get around this, you could research sticky sessions.

Comment: Wouldn't sharing the cache across multiple instances be better instead of sticky sessions?